# Android cannot find the memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have a Background service running which is syncing data to my server.

The leak happens in this code:

```
                DBCommunicator dataObj = (DBCommunicator) Class.forName(task.getDbObject()).getDeclaredConstructor(cArg).newInstance(context, DBCommunicator.normalDBSettings);
                DBCommunicator oldData = (DBCommunicator) dataObj.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(cArg).newInstance(context, DBCommunicator.sendNotiDBSettings);
                DBCommunicator newData = (DBCommunicator) dataObj.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(cArg).newInstance(context, DBCommunicator.sendNotiDBSettings);
                if (dateFrom == null) {
                    dateFrom = "";
                }
                url = CommonFunctions.getWebserviceUrl(context) +
                        task.getUrl() + "&from=" + URLEncoder.encode(dateFrom, "UTF-8") + "&to=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(dateUntil, "UTF-8");
                GetJSONFromUrl manager = new GetJSONFromUrl();

                ArrayList<?> jsonObject = manager.getJSONfromURL(url);
                //ArrayList<?> jsonObject = null;
                if (jsonObject == null) {
                    throw new Exception("JsonObject is null");
                }

                HashMap<String, String> values;
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.size(); i++) {
                    values = (HashMap<String, String>) jsonObject.get(i);
                    try {


                        if (values.get("Id") == null) {
                            throw new Exception("Parameter Id nicht gesetzt");
                        }

                        oldData.getSingleDataForField("Id", values.get("Id"));
                        if (values.get("Geloescht") != null && values.get("Geloescht").equals("1")) {
                            oldData.deleteData(true);

                        } else {
                            newData.setDataFromRecord(values);
                            if (!oldData.equals(newData)) {
                                oldData.deleteData(true);
                                newData.insertData();
                            }


                        }
                        values = null;
                    } catch (DBDataNotExists e) {
                        if (!(values.get("Geloescht") != null && values.get("Geloescht").equals("1"))) {
                            oldData.setDataFromRecord(values);
                            oldData.insertData();
                        }
                        e = null;

                    }
                    values = null;

                }
                dataObj.clean();
                dataObj.doAfterSync();
                dataObj = null;

                oldData.clean();
                oldData = null;

                newData.clean();
                newData = null;
                manager = null;
                jsonObject = null;
                dataObj = null;
```

The memory analyzer says:

> The thread at.stockserv.datasyncer.JobExecutor @ 0x135f6550 keeps local variables with total size 18.603.056 (37,90%) bytes.
>   The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "".
>
> JobExecutor -> Arraylist -> Object[21079] -> java.util.HashMap

I don't know where this amount of HashMap or Arraylist is coming from.

My JSON object ArrayList is just iterated through.I set it null.I don't know where this leak can happen.

Maybe someone can give me a hint where to start looking?

Comment: maybe [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) can help you finding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the memory leak in manager.getJSONfromURL(url);

There I had a Hashmap and and Arraylist filled in a loop.

Changed the code there now the memory leak is gone.